# List files recursively on OSX?

Tags: osx, ls

I want to find all PDF files in a directory and its subdirectories, on OSX.

I know there are some PDFs in subdirectories, because e.g. this produces lots of results:

```
ls myfolder/pdfs/*.pdf
```

All my Googling suggests I want `ls -R`, but this produces no results:

```
ls -R *.pdf
```

What am I doing wrong?

I can find some results this way:

```
ls -R | grep pdf
```

But I can't see this full paths to the files, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: You want to use `find` rather.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ls -R *.pdf` would invoke `ls` recursively on anything matching `*.pdf` (if there's nothing matching `*.pdf` in the current directory, you'll get no result, and if there is, it will only recurse into it if it's a directory).  `ls -R | grep pdf` would show you everything in the `ls -R` result that matches the regular expression `pdf`, which is not what you want.

This is what you need:

```
find myfolder -type f -name '*.pdf'
```

This will give you the pathnames of all regular files (`-type f`) in or below the `myfolder` directory whose filenames matches the pattern `*.pdf`.  The pattern needs to be quoted to protect it from the shell.

With the `zsh` shell (which recently became the default shell on macOS):

```
print -rC1 myfolder/**/*.pdf(.ND)
```

This would print out the pathnames of all regular files in or below the directory `myfolder` that have names ending in `.pdf`, in a single column.  The matching would include hidden names.  The `N` and `D` in the glob qualifier corresponds to setting the `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options in the `bash` shell (but only for this single globbing pattern), and the dot makes the pattern only match regular files (i.e. not directories etc.)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
find . -name \*.pdf -print
```

this should list pdf like

```
myfolder/foo/doc1.pdf
myfolder/bar/foo/doc2.pdf
```

note that `*` in `*.pdf` must be escaped if there is a pdf in starting directory.

Answer (score 2):

On the native `bash` shell you have on `macOS` Terminal (version 4 atleast), enable an extended glob option `globstar` to enable recursive glob match on nested sub-directories.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
printf '%s\n' **/*.pdf
```

The `nullglob` prevents filename patterns which match no files to expand to a null string, rather than themselves. With `globstar`, the pattern `**` used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and sub-directories.

To be a bit safe by avoiding setting the shell options on the current shell, you can set it in sub-shell instead

```
( shopt -s globstar nullglob; printf '%s\n' **/*.pdf ; )
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Bash on stock macOS is pretty ancient, some 3.x, I think globstar needs v4+

Comment: For some reason I thought that the latest releases had upgraded bash to 4.x as well as switching to zsh. [I was wrong.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx) You are right, globstar is a 4.x feature.

Comment: Your answer would need to mention that the 'native `bash` shell you have' is **not** going to support this. You'll have to use homebrew to get a more recent version.